How do i write a function for jasperreport in java spring boot
I'm trying to make a jasperreport, here's the following code
Controller:

    @GetMapping("getX")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getX() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(s.getX());
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("saveY")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveY(YDTO y){
        if(y.getName()==""||y.getSurname()=="") {
            throw new CustomException("custom");
        }
        if(y.getNumb().length()!=someNumb) {
            throw new CustomException2("custom2",y.getNumb().length());
        }
        Integer idNewY = s.saveY(y);
        if(idNewY == -1) {
            throw new CustomException3("custom3");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success:" +idNewY);
        
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("reportI")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getReport(String z) throws JRException, IOException{
        if(!s.existZ(z)) {
            throw new CustomException4("custom4", z);
        }
        byte[] report = s.createReport(z);
        if(report==null) {
            throw new CustomException4("custom4", z);
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "pdfName.pdf");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(report);
        
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotFoundZException(RuntimeException e){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }

Service:
public List<XDTO> getX() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        List<X> x = xr.findAll();
        List<XDTO> xDTO = new LinkedList<>();
        for(X p: x) {
            XDTO dto = new XDTO();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(p, dto);
            xDTO.add(dto);
        }
        return xDTO;
    }

    public int saveY(YDTO y) {
        Y newY = new Y();
        newY.setName(y.getName());
        newY.setSurname(y.getSurname());
        try {
            Y yc = yr.save(newY);
            return yc.getIdY();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public boolean existZ(String z) {
        Z newZ = zr.findByName(z);
        if(newZ!=null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public byte[] createReport(String z, and should be date) throws JRException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Number : "+ir.getIZ(z).size());
        if (ir.getIZ(z).size() > 0) {
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ir.getIZ(z));
            java.io.InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperreports/nameOfJrxml.jrxml");
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("z", z);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
            inputStream.close();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(byteArrayOutputStream));
            exporter.exportReport();
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }
        return null;
    }

Exception:
public class CustomException4 extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public CustomException4(String message, String value) {
        super(message+", Value: "+value);
    }

}

I also have regular repo's and dto's
The report template is created, and the main issue is the date, i dont know how to use it in the report
Date needs to be parsed in some sort of way, do not know how
It needs the strict date format, i think its yyyy-mm-dd, MySQL Database is being used

link Just seen this, will probably help

I was missing swagger configuration
`@Configuration
public class SwaggerConf {
@Bean
GroupedOpenApi controllerApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("groupName")
            .packagesToScan("com.example.demo.controller")
            .pathsToMatch("/path/**")
            .build(); 
}

}`
